# What group is $U(21)/\langle4\rangle$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Given $G = U(21)$ and $H=\langle4\rangle$, what is the group $G/H$ isomorphic to?

I've calculated $G/H$ to be $\{\langle4\rangle, 2\langle4\rangle, 5\langle4\rangle, 10\langle4\rangle\}$, but I can't figure out what group would be isomorphic to it.

My guess is to look for a group with elements $\{1, 2, 5, 10\}$ or some similar elements, but I'm struggling to come up with anything.

Is there some formula or theorem I've missed?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Is that not a standard group? Integers under multiplication mod 21? Pardon me if it's not. My professor might define it different from the general math community. Edit: At least, I believe that is the description of the group. Let me clarify just in case: U(n) is all positive integers a < n such that gcd(a,n) = 1

Comment: The more common notation is $(\Bbb{Z}/21\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$, but $U(21)$ is not uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're off to a good start; you've found that $U(21)/\langle 4\rangle$ has four elements, and you've found representatives for the cosets in $U(21)$. This allows you to make a multiplication table. There aren't many groups of $4$ elements, so you will quickly see which group it is.

Comment: So either $Z(4)$ or the klein four-group? I cant see how it would be $Z(4)$, but I don't think we've learned about klein groups... Though from what I'm seeing it looks to be that one. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}
\langle 4\rangle^2 &=\langle 4\rangle\\
(2\langle 4\rangle)^2&=4\langle 4\rangle\\
&=\langle 4\rangle\\
(5\langle 4\rangle)^2&=4\langle 4\rangle\\
&=\langle 4\rangle\\
(10\langle 4\rangle)^2&=16\langle 4\rangle\\
&=\langle 4\rangle.
\end{align}$$